# Return a single value for each select option

Tags: php, html, select

So I have a simple select form as follows:

```
<select>
  <option value=''>1st db</option>
  <option value=''>2nd db</option>
</select>
```

and I'm getting all available databases on the server with PDО thus listing them all. Now my question is how could I append every single database to its corresponding option value so that it may be selected afterwards for further 'manipulation'.

For example:

```
<select>
  <option value='<?php firstdb ?>'>1st db</option>
  <option value='<?php seconddb ?>'>2nd db</option>
</select>
```

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: How about a PHP foreach loop to print the options out?

Comment: It prints all out and I need a single value for each option

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by further manipulation, neither the value that you want to output to each option but that's doable with a php foreach. Example:

```
foreach($databases as $db){
?>
    <option value='<?=$db->value ?>'> <?=$db->name?> </option>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are already able to get the list of databases from the server. Hopefully you are retrieving them in an array.

My PDO query to retrieve the array of databases:

```
function showdb() {
    global $db;
    global $database;
    $sql = "SHOW DATABASES";
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        return $result;
    }
    catch (PDOException $exc) {
        return '0';
    }
}
```

Where I call the function to get the array for use:

```
$databases = showdb();
```

And the loop to use to get your select menu:

```
echo '<select>';
foreach ($databases as $db) {
    echo '<option value="'.$db['Database'].'">'.$db['Database'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```